# Visual Studio 2019 for Mac lacks Xamarin.Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to install Visual Studio for Mac 2019 with Xamarin, following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation?view=vsmac-2019).

All goes seemingly well, I do select Xamarin (in this case it's grayed out because this is not my first attempt, but I selected it manually the first time):
[image]

Yet when I open after installation, the SDK doesn't seem to be available:
[image]
[image]

Visual Sudio for Mac 2019 community, version 8.9.3, fresh install.

How do I get the Android SDK to work? I do I debug this problem?

Comment: It seems okay when you installed Android package. The version matched the requirement. You could try to uninstall and reinstall. If it still do not find the SDK Manager, you could  try to report a problem with Visual Studio for Mac, select Help > Report a Problem from the menu bar.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I tried reinstalling, but somehow (as seen on the screenshot), Xamarin was left from a previous install? How to I make sure I am starting from a clean slate, no Xamarin left?

Comment: Follow the stpes in the link for MAC. It provides all the details for Android. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall?view=vsmac-2019

Comment: Please install Android Studio properly your Android SDK problem of Visual Studio is resolved after that.

Comment: I seem to have come further with the uninstall link. It means that the update process failed and borked the install, had to reinstall from scratch. I've come further, but maybe not home yet though, will update.